# Assign whatever value is smaller or larger to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I often find myself doing these sort of ternary constructs which seem to lack elegance:

```
pixels = ( pixels > (canvas.top + canvas.left) ) ? canvas.top + canvas.left : pixels;
```

Is there a more succinct way stating `pixels = whatever is smaller`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use Math.min:

```
Math.min(pixels, canvas.top + canvas.left)
```

Here is a [reference of what you can do with Math object.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp)

Comment: Ah, I think I avoid the Math object just because of its name, but it has some pretty nifty methods, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Math.min(x,y)`

```
pixels = Math.min(pixels, canvas.top + canvas.left);
```

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) for `Math.min()`.  It can be used with two or more arguments and returns the smallest value.  And a [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) for all the Math functions.